# Using PHP/IIS to connect to a different server

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to connect to a different computer so I can connect to a specific instance on mssql_server. I have PHP configured on IIS, but I am not sure how to connect to the separate computer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something to connect with.  A quick search sent me to [php.net's sqlsrv-connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php).  The bit in there about the `connection string` is what you'd need to define, to connect to the appropriate machine / database using the appropriate user / password.